# New cannot be used on an interface

Tags: vb.net

I have the following class:

```
Public Class Class1
    Public Function Create() As IDbDataAdapter
        Try
            Dim da As New IDbDataAdapter(CommandString, IDbConnection)
        Catch ex As Exception
            ' ...
        End Try
    End Function
End Class
```

Visual basic intellisense keep telling me that using new IDbDataAdapter cannot be used on an interface, so what's wrong with my code as I don't get it

Comment: Interfaces just define the signatures of methods/properties and not the actual implementations. You simply cannot create instances of interfaces for that reason.

Comment: Exactly what the error is telling you.  You can't create an instance of an interface, you have to create an instance of a *class*.

Comment: I just wanted to add for future people searching for this error, it can appear for more than just this DataAdapter.

I came across this error with code that worked originally but after adding a reference to Excel, it used Font in its own way. So my attempted reference to System.Drawing.Font broke since I was just using New Font and it attempted to use Excel's instead.

Not an answer for your specific question, but hopefully helpful to others with the same error.

Comment: Like JRockwood, I want to add this happened to me also, with code that compiled successfully for years using MyTable = New Datatable. Suddenly one day I am getting little red squiggles all over my code stating that 'New cannot be used on an interface.' Apparently something changed in Interop Excel. This may help others who land on this page in the future regarding this error message.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot create a new instance of an interface or an abstract class. An interface only defines the method signatures of a class and has no behaviour.

Is there a concrete implementation of this interface (a non abstract class)?

In you example, IDbDataAdapter is implemented by this:
IDbDataAdapter foo = new SqlDataAdapter()

It's also implemented by OleDataAdapter and a number of classes. The advantages of them implementing the same interface being that we can use them interchangeably.